# RequestContextFilter not applied if management port differs from server port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Normally Spring Boot maps a `RequestContextFilter` to `/*`. However, when you configure the `management.server.port` to have another value than the `server.port`, this behaviour breaks. The filter will not be applied to the management URL's. This I did not expect. The reason why I need the filter is because I want to secure all endpoints (application and management) with OAuth2. At some point Spring Security requires a request scoped  `OAuth2ClientContext`. This only works if the request in linked to the current thread (which is the case when requests pass the `RequestContextFilter`).
Just wondering if this is working as intended or if this is really a bug.

I can be easily reproduced by creating a simple application via start.spring.io; adding actuator support and changing the server ports (e.g 8080 and 8081). Hitting the health point will never get into the filter (checked by setting a breakpoint).

Comment: The issue has been reported on Github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12546
A workaround has been provided.